# OAuth2 password grant and Basic Authentication

Tags: authentication, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I'm developing a solution that has: an Authorization Server (AS), a Resource Server and two clients. The two clients are: a web app with Angular 2 and a mobile app with Angular 2 + Ionic 2. I have started to develop the Authorization Server following this sample https://github.com/Baeldung/spring-security-oauth

For both the clients, I have decided to use the "Password Code Grant" because the client are trusted by the AS.

But now I have a problem storing the "client secret code" on the apps. Because the API (.../oauth/token) is secured by Basic Authentication so every time that I ask a token to the AS I need to send something like that:

```
curl.exe -v -u client_id:client_secret http://localhost:8080/backend/oauth/token -d grant_type=password -d client_id=client_id -d username=admin -d password=admin
```

So, the questions are:

1. Where I can store safely the client secret code on the apps?
2. Is it safe to remove the Basic Authentication from the oauth API?
3. Have I use another code grant type?

Thank you,
Paolo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Applications running in a browser (Angular) are not able to keep their secrets safe, so I would choose the OAuth2 Implicit flow. The implicit flow requires the use of HTTPS for communication with your Authorization Server, since the tokens are transferred over the network.

You should not remove the authentication from the token endpoint - it would compromise other flow types. For example the authorization grant flow doesn't require the client to be served by HTTPS and the auth code can be visible to anyone, so the token endpoint secret is important there (the Resource Server must ask for the tokens using HTTPS).

Using the implicit flow, you will have to check the validity time of the access token and request a new one before the current one expires. For example using the `prompt=none` auth request parameter.